# TestFlight with multiple Apple ID's and Teams

Tags: ios, testflight, apple-id

So I find it frustrating that Apple allow's an Apple ID to be in multiple Developer/Enterprise teams but with that same Apple ID you can only login to 1 iTunesConnect team.

I fixed it by creating a second Apple ID with myemail+company@gmail.com and added it to the Enterprise team of the company and they added me as a user for iTunes Connect. I can login and everything right now.

I've created an app and now I want to use TestFlight to distribute it amongst people in the company. If I login to iTunes Connect and try to add a New App I can choose a Bundle ID from a drop down but the Bundle ID I'm using for my application is not showing up. Also I see Bundle ID's that are not in the Member Center's Certificates/App ID's/Profiles.

How can I set everything up so I can distribute my app with TestFlight? I have all kinds of certificates and profiles but I can't see what's what anymore. I saw the [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/101790/ios-beta-testing-with-testflight-tutorial) but they begin without all the certificates and Member Center setup.

Here is what I have:

- a Development, Distribution and APNs Development certificate.
- an App ID like com.company.app-name
- multiple registered devices
- a XC Ad Hoc iOS Distribution Wildcard profile, a XC Ad Hoc iOS Distribution profile for com.company.app-name, a App-Name iOS Development profile for com.company.app-name and a App-Name iOS UniversalDistribution profile for com.company.app-name.

When I try to Validate or Submit to App Store after archiving the app in Xcode it says "Wildcard App IDs can not be used to create In House provisioning profiles. Please use an Explicit App ID." I thought I was using an explicit app id with com.company.app-name?